# Is $T: H_{1} \to H_{2}$ a contraction if $|\langle y, Tx \rangle| \leq (1-\varepsilon) ||x|| \cdot ||y||$ for an orthonormal basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ be finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, with $\textrm{dim}(H_{i}) = n_{i}$ for $i = 1, 2$.

Let $\\{ e_{i} \\}$ and $\\{f_{j}\\}$ be orthonormal bases for $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ respectively.
Let $T: H_{1} \to H_{2}$ is such that for any $e_{i}, f_{j}$:
$$|\langle f_{j}, Te_{i} \rangle| \leq (1-\varepsilon) \cdot ||e_{i}||\cdot||f_{i}|| $$
for some $M \geq 0$ and $\varepsilon > 0$.

Is $T$ a contraction, i.e. $||T|| \leq 1$?

---

What I tried so far: if the inequality holds for all $x \in H_{1}$ and $y \in H_{2}$, then taking $y = Tx$:

$$||Tx||^2 = \langle Tx, Tx\rangle \leq (1-\varepsilon) \cdot ||x|| \cdot ||Tx||$$
and thus $||Tx|| \leq (1-\varepsilon) ||x||$ which means it would be true.

So I tried showing for any $x \in H_{1}, y \in H_{2}$. Let $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n_{1}}\alpha_{i}e_{i}$ and $y = \sum_{j=1}^{n_{2}}\beta_{j}f_{j}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
|\langle y, Tx \rangle| &=& \left| \sum_{i=1, j=1}^{n_{1}, n_{2}} \alpha_{i}\beta_{j} \langle f_{j}, Te_{i} \rangle \right| \\\\
&\leq& \sum_{i=1, j=1}^{n_{1}, n_{2}} |\alpha_{i}| |\beta_{j}| |\langle f_{j}, Te_{i} \rangle | \\\\
&\leq& \sum_{i=1, j=1}^{n_{1}, n_{2}} |\alpha_{i}| |\beta_{j}| (1-\varepsilon)||e_{i}||\cdot||f_{j}|| \\\\
&=& (1-\varepsilon)\sum_{i=1, j=1}^{n_{1}, n_{2}} |\alpha_{i}| |\beta_{j}|
\end{eqnarray}
and from here I could use the equivalence of norms for finite dimensional spaces to estimate this with $||x||^2 = \sqrt{n_{1}}\sum_{i=1}^{n_{1}}|\alpha_{i}^2|$, and $||y||$ likewise, but this gives me a large norm for $T$.

Since my first triangle inequality is rather crude, I was wondering if I might get something lower.

Comment: What are $x, y$ in $|\langle f_{j}, Te_{i} \rangle| \leq (1-\varepsilon) \cdot ||x||\cdot||y||$?

Comment: I have corrected it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the $2 \times 2$ matrix
$$ \pmatrix{3/4 & 3/4\cr 3/4 & 3/4} $$
with orthonormal basis $\pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr}, \pmatrix{0\cr 1\cr}$.

Comment: The answer was more straightforward than I thought, thank you (and filling the matrix as such for any size yields the same result).